# The method fromMessage(String, Class<T extends BaseObject>) in the type MessageConverter is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<T>)

Tags: java

I have this Java code:

```
public abstract class BaseObject implements Serializable {
    ...
}

public interface MessageConverter {
    <T extends BaseObject> T getMessage(String message, Class<T> requiredType);
}

public abstract class AbstractMessageConverter implements MessageConverter {
    ...
}

public class WebMessageConverter extends AbstractMessageConverter {
    public <T extends BaseObject> T getMessage(String message, Class<T> requiredType) {
        final T data;
        ...
        return data;
    }
}

public class Utils {
    private static <T> T getItemType(String value, Class<T> requiredType, MessageConverter messageConverter) throws Exception
    {
        if (BaseObject.class.isAssignableFrom(requiredType))
        {
            return (T) messageConverter.getMessage(value, requiredType);
        }
        return (T) toRequiredType(value, requiredType);
    }

    public static <T> T toRequiredType(Object value, Class<T> requiredType)
    {
        final T data;
        ...
        return data;
    }
}
```

The following line:

```
return (T) messageConverter.getMessage(value, requiredType);
```

Causes:

```
The method getMessage(String, Class<T extends BaseObject>)
in the type MessageConverter is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<T>)
```

**how to fix this error?**

Comment: Where is `fromMessage` defined? Did you mean `getMessage`?

Comment: My mistake, fromMessage is getMessage

Comment: `T` in your class `Utils` is not an extend of `BaseObject`, try to cast it.

Answer (score 1):

The signature on `WebMessageConverter` expects a subtype of `BaseObject` when it declares `<T extends BaseObject>`.

The signature on the `Utils` has no such restriction as it uses a plain `<T>`, it would e.g. allow `Class<String>` to be used. That's why the compiler complains.

To resolve, declare the methods in `Utils` like this:

```
private static <T extends BaseObject> T getItemType(String value, Class<T> requiredType, MessageConverter messageConverter) throws Exception
```